# Why do I need to define the parameter name other than "this" in IIFE when I'm passing "this" as an argument?

Tags: javascript

I ran into an issue with the naming of parameters and arguments. In the IIFE, when I pass `this` as an argument, why do I need to re-name it at the parameter side.

When I rename `this`, the function is able to refer to proper `this`. When I do not, I'm getting `unexpected token this`.

```
const obj = {
  foo: 'bar',
  met() {
    (function(global) {
      console.log(global); // works fine
    })(this);
  },
  met2() {
    (function(this) { // unexpected token this
      console.log(this);
    })(this);
  },
};

obj.met();
obj.met2();
```

I did not understand why I'm getting an `unexpected token error`.

Comment: You can use `function() { console.log(this); }.call(this)`

Comment: @Bergi I don't think I asked how to pass `this`. I asked why we should not name the parameter as `this` and Quentin has give the answer.

Comment: `this`, along with a list of other reserved words, cannot be use as variables, labels, or function names: See https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp, so for example, if you try to use `function(false) {...}` it will fail too.

Comment: @SaiKrishnaSarathVelamuri I saw his answer, my comment is meant as a supplement to it.

Comment: @Bergi I never knew duplicate and supplement meant the same.

Comment: @Sai My comment was not related to the duplicate vote. The duplicate has an answer that explains (amongst other things) why you were getting the *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this*.

Answer (score 2):

[`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is a keyword, so you can't create a new variable named `this`.